# jQuery autocomplete - clicking submit button does not count as "change"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Yeah, this is indeed my third or fourth question about jQuery UI Autocomplete. My latest annoyance is that clicking the 'submit' button in a form does not seem to count as a 'change' for jQuery. When my input box changes, jQuery runs some javascript to force a match against a list of acceptable inputs and their values:

```
jQuery("#Resource").autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp(jQuery.trim(request.term).replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), "i" );
    var matches = jQuery.grep(resources, function(value) {
     return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
    });
    response(matches.length ? matches : [{ label: "No Result Found", value: "" }]);
   },
   focus: function(event, ui) {
    jQuery('#Resource').val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
   },          
   select: function(event, ui) {
    jQuery('#Resource').val(ui.item.label);
    jQuery('#EmployeeNumber').val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
    for(var i in resources){
     jQuery('#EmployeeNumber').val("");
     if(resources[i].label.toLowerCase()==jQuery('#Resource').val().toLowerCase()) {
      jQuery('#EmployeeNumber').val(resources[i].value);
      break;
     }
    }
   }

  });
```

If the EmployeeNumber (hidden) input already has a value, entering an invalid name and then tabbing or clicking off of the input box clears this value, **however** if you instead immediately hit the form `Submit` button, it does not seem to count as a 'change' and the `POST` data includes the previous EmployeeNumber value - making what should be an incorrect input 'sort of' correct!

Is there either some way I can make the jQuery recognise that clicking 'Submit' is also a change, or else some way I can get the `Submit` button to notify the jQuery that the `Resource` input has been clicked off of?

**UPDATE**:

In the end, I got around this by using what I consider a rather hacky method - I abandoned the 'change' event of the auto-complete box and did that matching myself manually when the user clicks submit. The way it work now is that if the user chooses a name by clicking on the auto-complete drop-down menu, the EmployeeNumber value will be filled in by the auto-complete jQuery code. If the user just types a name and hits submit, then the matching is instead done by the forceCheck() function. Of course this function will automatically match against the first name regardless of whether or not there is a second identical name, but unfortunately in what seems like the **weirdest** quirk I've ever seen, any code after the end of that for loop does *not* get executed, even if there is no 'return' statement in the loop. After the loop finishes the submit request just continues... it's so very odd.

```
<fieldset class="submit">
    <input id="Submit" name="Submit" type="Submit" class="Submit" value ="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('Resource').value = jQuery.trim(document.getElementById('Resource').value);forceCheck();"/>
</fieldset>

...


<script type="text/javascript">

    ...

    // Force a resource name check when the user hits the submit button. Necessary because if user changes Resoruce
    // input then hits submit directly (no click or tab off), the jQuery 'change' event (see below) isn't fired
    // until *after* the submit button has begun processing, which is too late.
    function forceCheck() {
        for(var i in resources) {
            document.getElementById("EmployeeNumber").value = "";
            if(resources[i].label.toUpperCase() == document.getElementById("Resource").value.toUpperCase()) {
                document.getElementById("EmployeeNumber").value = resources[i].value;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#Resource").autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var matcher = new RegExp(jQuery.trim(request.term).replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), "i" );
                var matches = jQuery.grep(resources, function(value) {
                    return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
                });
                response(matches.length ? matches : [{ label: "No Result Found", value: "" }]);
            },
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery('#Resource').val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },          
            select: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery('#Resource').val(ui.item.label);
                jQuery('#EmployeeNumber').val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },  
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

If anyone knows a better way than this, I would very much appreciate your answer - or if you know why the remainder of my forceCheck function might not run... Otherwise, I will post this post as an answer to my own question tomorrow, and accept it when I can (2 days afterwards, I believe).

**Final Update**:

Well, it's been more than 24 hours (quite a lot more), so I've posted my solution up as an "answer". I'll leave it a few more days then accept it if there's still no other answer.

Comment: Bit confused. Tried manually firing the Resource inputs `onblur` even from the `onclick` event of the Submit button. Added an `alert` statement into the change function to see if it worked. When I hit `Submit` the alert fired, but the EmployeeNumber wasn't changed in the POST - it's like it had already been recorded before the onclick event fired, or at least before the change event fired.

Comment: Indeed. Tested the code by adding in multiple 'alerts' to the `change` function. When just clicking off, they all run. When the `change` function is running due to the submit button having been clicked, the only one that runs is the first one. Even if I put two `alerts` in a row, only the first one runs - and I don't know if anything runs if I don't put an alert first...

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. Forcing the `onblur` event does **not** kick off the `change` event - the reason I was getting an alert box is that the autocomplete does register a `change`, just after the submit method has already started processing. The reason I usually managed to get one alert box up was due to the delay before leaving the page while processing occured...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the change handler is called to late (after submit) is that autocomplete is coded asynchronously (with a lot of setTimeout(...)).
The change-event is called 150 ms after the blur-event.

My solution is also a bit hacky, but you can keep the autocomplete-code apart from the submit. This is also easy to remove if the autocomplete-widget is rewritten in a more synchronous way.

```
$("#mysubmit").click(function (event) {
//Wait for autocomplete to change value
    setTimeout(function() {
        //Do submit
        ...
    }, 250 ); //Make sure delay is greater than 150 ms, as in autocomplete widget.
    event.preventDefault(); //Don't submit now
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but this is where I ended up when trying to solve this same issue, and I think I have a unique solution. It's certainly not a perfect solution since it involves accessing 'private' functions, but it works (so far) and it looks much cleaner.

I force trigger the change event before submitting:

```
$('#yourAutoCompleteForm').submit(function() {
    $('#yourAutoCompleteInput').data("autocomplete")._change();
    //the rest of your submit
}
```

My submit goes on to verify a custom attribute set by my change callback. They could probably share a scope and just use a var...

Answer (score 1):

I understand that about a year pass from a question but I encountered the same problem. I use the last for now jquery ui 1.8.13. I solve the problem this way:

```
var acinaction = false;  // autocomlete in edit stage flag
var needsubmit = false;  // submit action asked
jQuery("#Resource").keypress(function(event) {
    // if any key pressed then we set autocomplete in edit stage flag
    if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    acinaction = true;
}).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) {
        // user choose an item from dropdown menu
        // do validation here if necessary
        ...
        // unset autocomplete in edit stage flag
        acinaction = false;
    },
    change: function(event,ui) {
        if( acinaction ) {
            // user input some characters into input field and move focus away
            // without choosing any items from dropdown menu
            // may be clicking submit button
            // do validation here if necessary
            ...
            acinaction = false;
            if( form_is_valid && needsubmit ) {
                // if submit flag is set then try submit again
                JQuery('#Form').submit();
            }
        }
    }
});
JQuery('#Form').submit(function() {
    // if autocomplete in edit stage then cancel form submition
    if( acinaction ) {
        needsubmit = true;
        return false;
    }
    // autocomplete change event is done here
});
```

The code is ugly but it should show the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, jquery-ui 1.8.4 **sort of** fixes the problem (see [changelog](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.8.4)):

- Fixed: Combobox/Autocomplete doesn't
  save value unless control loses focus

Have you been able to test it? Because it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am using 1.8.5 and still seeing the same problem.  In my case, if someone types something with no match and then presses Enter, the form is submitted without the change() event firing before the post occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a method to solve this matter,

first, add this script to yours

```
$('#your_form:input').change(function(){
   $('#your_form').data('changed',true);
});
```

and then in your submit clicking validataion scripts, add the script as below,

```
 if(!$('#your_form').data('changed'))  return false;
```

I found it really works though I think it is not the best way.

Sorry, it'a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

To exapand on Tvartom's answer, here's what I put in my page load code:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  var form = $(this);
  if (form.find('.ui-autocomplete-input').length &&
      !form.data('already-submitted')) {
    // delay the submit by 250 ms
    form.data('already-submitted', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
      form.submit();
      form.data('already-submitted', false);
    }, 250);
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

This automatically applies to all forms that have autocomplete inputs in them. You need to be careful with other form submit event callbacks, though - you need to check if `form.data('already-submitted')` and if it's false, do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add

```
submit: function(event,ui) {
// same thing as your change:
}
```

Comment: jQuery UI autocomplete doesn't have a `submit` event... See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#events).

Answer (score -2):

Use `blur` instead of `change`. In my case it worked!